# How can I make an attribute mandatory in OpenLDAP?

Tags: linux, security, ldap, openldap

Our legacy OpenLDAP environment has entries, e.g. "Manager" that should always be present, but that are missing.  If the Manager field is present and correct, it contains the OU of the person who is responsible for the person with that attribute.  The missing entries appear to be due to inconsistent processes in the creation of accounts.  I'm looking for a way to enforce the presence of a **something** in that Manager attribute.  It may be wrong, but that's another kettle of fish.  I want to at least make sure there's an entry, even if it's "Needs a Manager."  Thoughts?  Suggestions?  I'm a dabbler in LDAP who has inherited this mess, so go easy, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done through the *directory schema* – the entries' `objectClass` definitions. The main purpose of each objectClass is to specify which attributes are required, and which are optional but permitted.

For example, this is how the built-in /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema defines the `person` class – marking attributes 'cn' and 'sn/surname' (though oddly not 'gn/givenName') mandatory for every entry that has `objectClass: person`:

```
objectclass ( 2.5.6.6 NAME 'person'
              DESC 'RFC2256: a person'
              SUP top
              STRUCTURAL
              MUST ( sn $ cn )
              MAY ( userPassword $ telephoneNumber $ seeAlso $ description ) )
```

So if your account entries already have a custom objectClass defined, just add the required attributes into the `MUST` list of that class schema definition (preferably after batch-updating all entries to actually have that attribute).

But I wouldn't recommend modifying the "standard" object class definitions (though it can be done). Instead, if your account entries don't have a custom objectClass yet, you might want to *create* one and start using it everywhere. (Most likely as a 'structural' class that derives from whatever you're currently using.)

Though you'll still need a way to enforce the usage of that `objectClass`... (I kind of remember OpenLDAP having the ability to enforce which objectClasses could be used under which subtrees, but can't seem to find it now.)

---

Note that in the default OpenLDAP schemas (cosine), `manager` is not a 'string' attribute – it's specifically defined to contain a DN value. This means `Needs a manager` wouldn't be accepted as a valid value.

If you need a placeholder, you would need to use something like `cn=Needs a manager` that *looks* like a DN, even if it's a nonexistent one.